# Google App maker calculated model query

Tags: google-app-maker

How to load and unload app maker calculated model data source, normal query filters are not working for calculated data source. We have requirement to load data source with filters after the initial data load.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on your server side implementation. Basically, you are receiving `query` as a parameter. From the `query` you can get values for your `filters`, `parameters`, `paging`, `sorting`, etc. and handle them with scripting. You can find such examples in [App Maker Templates](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/), for instance in [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/).